# AsyncTask in "Wait" status in DDMS after completing its execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask (doing some network connection check in background), which let's say does nothing in onPostExecute.
Problem is when I look into DDMS Threads view I see my AsyncTask still waiting for smth, although work in background has completed and I've even exited app.

I don't think this behavior is normal, can someone pls enlight me?

```
public class CheckConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    private Integer forTask = null;

    public CheckConnectionTask(Integer forTask) {
        super();
        this.forTask = forTask;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground");
        Thread.currentThread().setName("CheckConnectionTask for task " + forTask);

        return DataUtils.isInternetConnectionAvailable(CurrentActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //do some UI work here, nothing for the moment

    }

}
```

Comment: asynctasks run in a thread pool. that means that the same thread is reused (but not renamed) after on asynctask is finished. once the asynctask is done, the thread will be waiting for the next asynctask to be executed.

Comment: d'oh, did'nt know that, it seems my approach is really wrong - I'm executing a new AsyncTask for every action in my app - basically, I check network connection every time I place a request to a web server, so I'll end up having lot of async tasks in wait status.

Comment: Can't AsyncTask be destroyed somehow? I'm thinking to get rid of it as soon as I get what I want from it. Should I just cancel it in onPostExecute()?

Comment: you don't need to worry about your asynctask, the threads are recycled by the thread pool (basically the pool has 10 threads to execute all of your asynctasks.)